# SQL Server: Should I overwrite existing file for additional backups?

Tags: sql-server

In the SQL Server 2012 wizard to backup a database, I previously created a 'full' backup.

Now I want to create a differential backup. However, the destination specified the same file name and I'm not sure what will happen when creating a new backup to that file in terms of restoration.

ie.

Will this append to the same file?

Will the full backup be replaced by the differential file? (Obviously this is not helpful)

Will something else happen?

Comment: As of my knowledge " full backup will be replaced by the differential file"

Comment: There is an option for both append as well overwrite while taking backup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]we can do both append as well overwrite while taking backup .

Please find the link:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191211(v=sql.105).aspx